# GCM device registration

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 in.demo.gcm.MainActivity$1.onClick:29 android.view.View.performClick:4438

I am getting above error,i add gcm.jar in my project but still my error not clear.
Please give me any other suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the error you are getting, but `gcm.jar` is obsolete. The recommended way to register to GCM is via the `GoogleCloudMessaging.register` method of the Google Play Services library.

The registration code (taken from the [official GCM demo app](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java)) looks like this :

```
/**
 * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
 * <p>
 * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
 * shared preferences.
 */
private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it
                // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device will send
                // upstream messages to a server that echo back the message using the
                // 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```